# Angular How to detect browser back button press before route changing

Tags: angular, routes

I'm using Angular 12 SPA app.
When user press the browser back button. I want to show the warning message before leave in current route url.
Current page "localhost/note"

If user click back button. url changed "localhost/home" then show the warning message(page is not changed, only url changed)

However, I want to show the message BEFORE route change.
I'm using HostListener. It shows alert after url/route change

```
@HostListener('window:popstate', ['$event'])
  onPopState(event: any) {
    alert("Do you really want to move other page?");
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to the stackoverflow. What you are looking for is `onbeforeunload` event, it should do the job. But check it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload), some browsers have limitations for it (like blocking pop-ups).

```typescript
@Directive()
export abstract class ComponentCanDeactivate {
  abstract canDeactivate(): boolean;

  @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
  unloadNotification($event: any) {
    if (!AuthService.isLogout && !this.canDeactivate()) {
      $event.returnValue = true;
    }
  }
}
```

We used the code above together with a route guard which check Angular Router navigation. If result of `canDeactivate` is `false`, route guard won't let you leave the current route.

```typescript
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class UnsavedChangesGuard implements CanDeactivate<ComponentCanDeactivate> {
  constructor() {}

  canDeactivate(
    component: FormCanDeactivate,
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot,
    next: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): boolean | Observable<boolean> {
    const someUrlCheck = next.url.includes(someRoute);
    return component.canDeactivate() ? true : component.openConfirmCancelDialog(someUrlCheck);
  }
}
```

In our case `FormCanDeactivate` abstract class extends another `ComponentCanDeactivate`abstract class and provides default '*Are you sure you want to leave*' dialog.

```typescript
@Directive()
export abstract class FormCanDeactivate extends ComponentCanDeactivate {
  private _dialogConfig: ConfirmDialogData = initialDialogConfig;
  protected disableDiscard: boolean = false;

  get dialogConfig(): ConfirmDialogData {
    return this._dialogConfig;
  }

  set dialogConfig(value: ConfirmDialogData) {
    this._dialogConfig = value;
  }

  abstract get saveForm(): FormGroup | boolean;

  abstract submitForm(): void;

  abstract resetForm(): void;

  constructor(protected dialog: MatDialog) {
    super();
  }

  openConfirmCancelDialog(isLogout: boolean = false): Observable<boolean> {
    // ...
  }

  canDeactivate(): boolean {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for help me out:) However, ```window:beforeunload``` is only detect browser reload button not back button.

Comment: It detects also back button, but not in SPA application. You have to user route guard for this